# Not able to find database while joining 2 cache in ignite

Tags: ignite

I am working on utilizing distributed joins between multiple ignite cache. I loaded the required data in both the caches and while performing the join it fails while parsing the SQL suggesting "Database not found" (Please see the stack trace).

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Database "OFFER" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT "customOrganizationCache".Organization._key, "customOrganizationCache".Organization._val from Organization as organization, "customOfferCache".Offer as offer where organization._id = offer.relationships.customer.targets.key and organization._id = ? [90013-191]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
```

Below is my ignite config file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="offerCacheStoreFactory" class="javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder" factory-method="factoryOf">
<constructor-arg><value>com.xyz.exploreignite.cache.CustomOfferCacheStore</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="organizationCacheStoreFactory" class="javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder" factory-method="factoryOf">
<constructor-arg><value>com.xyz.exploreignite.cache.CustomOrganizationCacheStore</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="false"/>
<property name="clientMode" value="false"/>
<property name="gridName" value="clusterGrid"/>
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>               
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                <property name="backups" value="1"/>
                <property name="name" value="customOrganizationCache"/>
                <property name="readThrough" value="true"/>
                <property name="writeThrough" value="true"/>
                <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                <property name="writeBehindEnabled" value="true"/>
                <property name="copyOnRead" value="false"/>
                <property name="memoryMode" value="OFFHEAP_TIERED"/>
                <property name="atomicWriteOrderMode" value="PRIMARY"/>
                <property name="indexedTypes" >
        <list>
            <value>java.lang.String</value>
            <value>com.xyz.exploreignite.pojo.Organization</value>
        </list>
        </property>
        <!-- Cache store. -->
        <property name="cacheStoreFactory" ref="organizationCacheStoreFactory"/>
        <property name="swapEnabled" value="false"/>
        <property name="offHeapMaxMemory" value="0"/>
        <property name="evictionPolicy">
        <!-- LRU eviction policy. -->
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.eviction.lru.LruEvictionPolicy">
            <!-- Set the maximum cache size to 1 million (default is 100,000). -->
            <property name="maxSize" value="1000000"/>
        </bean>
        </property>
            </bean>
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
                <property name="backups" value="1"/>
                <property name="name" value="customOfferCache"/>
                <property name="readThrough" value="true"/>
                <property name="writeThrough" value="true"/>
                <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                <property name="writeBehindEnabled" value="true"/>
                <property name="copyOnRead" value="false"/>
                <property name="memoryMode" value="OFFHEAP_TIERED"/>
                <property name="atomicWriteOrderMode" value="PRIMARY"/>
                <property name="indexedTypes" >
        <list>
            <value>java.lang.String</value>
            <value>com.xyz.exploreignite.pojo.Offer</value>
        </list>
        </property>
        <!-- Cache store. -->
        <property name="cacheStoreFactory" ref="offerCacheStoreFactory"/>
        <property name="swapEnabled" value="false"/>
        <property name="offHeapMaxMemory" value="0"/>
        <property name="evictionPolicy">
        <!-- LRU eviction policy. -->
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.eviction.lru.LruEvictionPolicy">
            <!-- Set the maximum cache size to 1 million (default is 100,000). -->
            <property name="maxSize" value="1000000"/>
        </bean>
        </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>


    <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <!--
                    Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                    instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                    to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                -->
                <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">-->
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Below is the code that I am using while performing the join:

```
try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(
            // "/home/impadmin/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin/examples/config/example-cache-ss-cluster.xml"))
            // {
            "/home/xyz/msheth/install/apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin/examples/config/example-cache-ss-cluster.xml")) {

        try (IgniteCache<String, Offer> customOfferCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("customOfferCache");

                IgniteCache<String, Organization> customOrganizationCache = ignite
                        .getOrCreateCache("customOrganizationCache")) {


            SqlFieldsQuery joinQuery = new SqlFieldsQuery("select organization.displayName "
                    + "from Organization as organization, \"customOfferCache\".Offer as offer"
                    + " where organization._id = offer.relationships.customer.targets.key "
                    + "and organization._id = ?");

            joinQuery.setDistributedJoins(true);

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try (QueryCursor<List<?>> joinCursor = customOrganizationCache
                    .query(joinQuery.setArgs("542de0b83b2d445f0a0e0f53"))) {
                for (List<?> organizationEntry : joinCursor)
                    System.out.println("Organizations display name: " + organizationEntry);
            }

            System.out.println("Time to fetch join based record:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

        }

    }
```

Please help me to find the root cause.

Comment: This looks very weird. Can you provide the whole test as a small GitHub project. If I run it, it will be much easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: @Valentin, thanks for looking into this. I have pushed the code to public github @ https://github.com/mananstar2001/testignite. Please note that there are multiple test classes, mainly TestCustomOfferCacheLoad.java and TestCustomOrgCacheLoad.java for loading and setting up the cache & TestCustomOfferOrgCacheJoin.java for cache joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in this expression:

```
offer.relationships.customer.targets.key
```

Couple of considerations around this:

- You are allowed to have nested objects, however Ignite will create flat schema. E.g., `customer` field can be accessed as a member of `Offer` table, you should not provide this full path for this. Generally, you should try to avoid nested object when using SQL and create simple POJO classes instead.
- However, you are not allowed to query inside a collection. In your case the whole collection of `targets` is saved as a single object and you can't select based on its contents. You should have separate cache for `Target` objects and join it with other tables.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and would work it down to preserve objects in different cache, but additionally have 1 query on first bullet. If we have all nested fields as direct cache pojo members (in my case its the JSON object that is being mapped to POJO), how would Ignite differentiate between different section fields.To simplify, we have one field "offer/customer" and another field "offer/relationships/customer", while laying down the cache, both would be occupied with the same name customer field in offer object. How would the ignite differentiate between those.

Comment: Ignite will throw an exception in this case. However, `@QuerySqlField` annotation has optional `name` parameter that allow to override names and avoid such conflicts.